(OCP/NLP) Trying to solve optimal control with DAE system
I'm currently working with a tiltrotor UAV, with propellers divided into 2 parts: tilting and fixed. And my objective is to solve for vertical motion plan. With simplified dynamics I have the following equation:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{v}&=\frac{1}{m}(T_t\cos{(\eta+\alpha)}-T_f\sin{\alpha} -K_Dv^2)-g\sin{\gamma} \\
\dot{\gamma}&=\frac{1}{mv}(K_Lv^2+T_f\cos{\alpha}+T_t\sin{(\eta+\alpha)}-mg\cos{\gamma}) \\
\dot{\eta} &= \omega \\
\dot{s} &= v \\
\dot{h} &= v\sin{\gamma}
\end{align}
\tag{1}
$$
with: $x=(v,\gamma, \eta,s,h)^T$ and $u=(T_t, T_f, \omega)^T$
I can obtain optimal solution with this system using direct methods. However I want to fix $\gamma$ since by definition it's the path angle (angle between velocity and horizontal plane). With $\gamma$ fixed, and its derivative $\dot{\gamma}$ is zero, I got:
$$
\begin{aligned}
0=\dot{\gamma}&=\frac{1}{mv}(K_Lv^2+T_f\cos{\alpha}+T_t\sin{(\eta+\alpha)}-mg\cos{\gamma}) \\
&= K_Lv^2+T_f\cos{\alpha}+T_t\sin{(\eta+\alpha)} -mg\cos{\gamma}
\end{aligned} \tag{2}
$$
With this algebraic equation derived, I now have a system described by 4 ODEs and 1 algebraic equation, hence forming a DAE system.
My question then arises as what should I do next. Do I move to a direct method solver with DAE support, or by substituting $(2)$ into one of the ODEs - one about $\dot{v}$, this would eliminate a variable, and solve the system of new ODEs?
p.s. I actually tried substituting, I solved $(2)$ for $v^2$, which is:
$$
v^2=\frac{1}{K_L}(mg\cos{\gamma}-T_f\cos{\alpha}-T_t\sin{(\eta+\alpha)}) \tag{3}
$$
substituting $(3)$ into $(1)$ yields:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{v}&=\frac{1}{m}(T_t(\cos{(\eta+\alpha)}-\frac{K_D}{K_L}\sin{(\eta+\alpha)}) + T_f(\frac{K_D}{K_L}\cos{\alpha}-\sin{\alpha}))-g(\frac{K_D}{K_L}\cos{\gamma}-\sin{\gamma}) \\
\dot{\eta} &= \omega \\
\dot{s} &= v \\
\dot{h} &= v\sin{\gamma}
\end{aligned}\tag{4}
$$
However my current OCP solver reports that $(4)$ is infeasible. I know lots of stuff can cause a problem to be infeasible - not necessarily the model itself, but I just want to make sure my way of handling DAE system is correct or not.
Thanks!
